# Why does apachectl stop take a very long time to finish?

Tags: apache-2.4, timeout, startup, shutdown

I have a freshly installed CentOS 9 with Apache, and found that `apachectl stop` take very long to finish (as in always 1m30s).

I don't really have any clue where to look, I don't see any CPU bound processes while stopping, and `apachectl configtest` gives me a "Syntax OK".

When I do a `watch "ps ax | grep httpd"` I see a few processes gone quickly, and 4 lingering for that long time.

Right after a stop/start, it goes faster again.

**Update**
When I `kill` the PID that `systemctl status httpd` gives me, it stops a lot faster.

**Update**
I setup the `mod_status`, which works fine. But as soon as I run `apachectl stop`, the status page stops working.

**Update**
`apachectl -M` didn't work, but `httpd -M` does. Below the results.

```
[user@host ~]$ httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cache_socache_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 macro_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_redis_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 watchdog_module (shared)
 brotli_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 proxy_http2_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: Possibly waiting for open connections to die?

Comment: @vidarlo that seems to be it yes. Makes me wonder why my browser keeps the connection open and is there a way to force disconnect these?

Comment: @vidarlo when using `apachectl -k stop` I can see all connections go to `FIN_WAIT2`, but stay there quite some time.

Comment: stop forces stop the processes, unless very specific cases with third party modules or ver old http server versions your server should stop almost inmediately. Perhaps show more info of what is going on so we do not have to guess, like "apachectl -M" for the list of modules. Use mod_status module and check the server-status handler before shutting down to see what child processes are doing. And also show which mpm and setup you are using.

Comment: @DanielFerradal I added the list of modules. The setup is plain CentOS9, with some added modules. I haven't touched the config files (except for the certificates).

Answer (score 1):

(this started off as a comment, but was getting too big)

Yes, as @vidarlo says, some of the connections are not being dropped.

1. Provision server-status - this will show you what is still running after the stop is issued.
2. Check the KeepAliveTimeout - the default 5 seconds is much too high in most cases.
3. Also add some performance metrics in your logs. If you are at all bothered about quality of service then you should know what is taking a long time (and fix anything which is not running websockets).
4. Assuming you have a valid reason for forcing a faster shutdown then replace your shutdown mechanism with a script doing this:

- add iptables rule blocking new connection to httpd
- wait for your time limit to expire, checking the number of connections at intervals (except those in FIN_WAIT2)
- if the timer expires then kill -TERM the httpd master process (typically the one owned by root)
- if the number of connections is zero then kill -WINCH the master process (or do the normal stop)

Comment: Thanks, I did the `server-status`, but that stops working immediately after `apachectl stop` is issued. After that 1m30s of silence. In `ps ax` I can see a few threads that stay open (no way of seeing what they are doing now though). I am suspecting some Python code now (my app runs Djanho in wsgi), so onwards to that ;-)